# PHP isset() with multiple parameters

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to work with AJAX autocompletes and I am having a few problems with getting the two languages to work in synergy.

When I replace all the issets with only 1 $_POST the snippet below will work, however by adding another $_POST I get an error on line 5.

```
<?php 

require_once '../Configuration.php';
if (isset($_POST['search_term'] . $_POST['postcode']) == true && empty ($_POST['search_term'] . $_POST['postcode']) == false) {
$search_term = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['search_term'] . $_POST['postcode']);
$query = mysql_query("SELECT `customer_name`,`postcode` FROM `Customers` WHERE `customer_name` LIKE '$search_term%' ");
while(($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) !== false) {
    //loop
    echo '<li>',$row['customer_name'] . $row['postcode'] '</li>';
}
}


?>
```

Any advice on why it is throwing this error would be much appreciated. Thanks.

I understand I should be using mysqli, I am just trying to get the logic first :)

Js:

Primary.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.autosuggest').keyup(function() {

    var search_term = $(this).attr('value');
    var postcode = $_GET['postcode'];
    //alert(search_term); takes what is typed in the input and alerts it
    $.post('ajax/search.php', {search_term:search_term, postcode:postcode},     function (data) {
        $('.result').html(data);
        $('.result li').click(function() {
            var result_value = $(this).text();
            $('.autosuggest').attr('value', result_value);
            $('.result').html('');

        });
    });
});
});
```

Comment: One `isset` per array index. By the way `isset == true` is redundant.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

The parameter(s) to `isset()` must be a variable reference and not an expression (in your case a concatenation); but you can group multiple conditions together like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['search_term'], $_POST['postcode'])) {
}
```

This will return `true` only if *all* arguments to `isset()` are set and do not contain `null`.

Note that `isset($var)` and `isset($var) == true` have the same effect, so the latter is somewhat redundant.

**Update**

The second part of your expression uses `empty()` like this:

```
empty ($_POST['search_term'] . $_POST['postcode']) == false
```

This is wrong for the same reasons as above. In fact, you don't need `empty()` here, because by that time you would have already checked whether the variables are set, so you can shortcut the complete expression like so:

```
isset($_POST['search_term'], $_POST['postcode']) && 
    $_POST['search_term'] && 
    $_POST['postcode']
```

Or using an equivalent expression:

```
!empty($_POST['search_term']) && !empty($_POST['postcode'])
```

**Final thoughts**

You should consider using `filter` functions to manage the inputs:

```
$data = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, array(
    'search_term' => array(
        'filter' => FILTER_UNSAFE_RAW,
        'flags' => FILTER_NULL_ON_FAILURE,
    ),
    'postcode' => array(
        'filter' => FILTER_UNSAFE_RAW,
        'flags' => FILTER_NULL_ON_FAILURE,
    ),
));

if ($data === null || in_array(null, $data, true)) {
    // some fields are missing or their values didn't pass the filter
    die("You did something naughty");
}

// $data['search_term'] and $data['postcode'] contains the fields you want
```

Btw, you can customize your filters to check for various parts of the submitted values.

Comment: One note - as of PHP 5.5.0 `empty()` also explicitly supports expressions.

Comment: You've way far advanced for me haha, I am literally just learning PHP. Thanks

Answer (score 12):

The parameters of `isset()` should be separated by a comma sign (`,`) and not a dot sign (`.`). Your current code concatenates the variables into a single parameter, instead of passing them as separate parameters.

So the original code evaluates the variables as a unified `string` value:

```
isset($_POST['search_term'] . $_POST['postcode']) // Incorrect
```

While the correct form evaluates them separately as variables:

```
isset($_POST['search_term'], $_POST['postcode']) // Correct
```

Answer (score 9):

You just need:

```
if (!empty($_POST['search_term']) && !empty($_POST['postcode']))
```

`isset && !empty` is redundant.

Answer (score 3):

Use the php's `OR (||)` logical operator for php `isset()` with multiple operator
e.g

```
if (isset($_POST['room']) || ($_POST['cottage']) || ($_POST['villa'])) {

}
```

Comment: This is wrong, and would generate notices if `$_POST['room']` is set and the rest isn't. You need to wrap all of these in a single `isset` and pass the last two variables as arguments, or you need to wrap them in an `isset` of their own.