# Php session error undefined index

Tags: php, session, indexing, undefined

```
session_start();

if (isset($_POST['username'] , $_POST['password'])) {

    $extractabout = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = :username && password = :password");

    $extractabout->execute([
        'username' => $_POST['username'],
        'password' => $_POST['password']
    ]);

    $infos = $extractabout->rowCount() ? $extractabout : [] ;

    foreach ($infos as $info) {
        if(!empty($info['username']) && !empty($info['password']) && !empty($info['id']) && !empty('role')) {
            $_SESSION['username'] == $info['username'];
            $_SESSION['password'] == $info['password'];         
        }

    }

    if(isset($_SESSION['username'], $_SESSION['password'], $_SESSION['user_id'], $_SESSION['role'])) {
        header("Location: test.php");
    }   

}

?>
```

I have an error when I give `$_SESSION['username']` the value of `$info['username']` called :

> Undefined index: username
>   Undifined index: password

Comment: Multiple errors spotted. `==` is different from `=`. Remember to `exit()` after `header("Location: $url");` call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't assign the values, you only have to use one `=` so use this:

```
$_SESSION['username'] = $info['username'];
$_SESSION['password'] = $info['password'];
```

Also i would put a `exit();` after each header so that you are sure the script stops to be executed!

```
header("Location: test.php");
exit();
```

Answer (score 0):

use `=` for assign values in session not `==`(compare).

Also what is `!empty('role')` i think it would be `!empty($info['role'])`

```
if(!empty($info['username']) && !empty($info['password']) && !empty($info['id']) && !empty($info['role'])) {
        $_SESSION['username'] = $info['username'];
        $_SESSION['password'] = $info['password'];                     
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have syntax errors in your code as,corrected one is:

```
if(!empty($info['username']) && !empty($info['password']) && !empty($info['id']) && !empty($info['role'])) {
    $_SESSION['username'] = $info['username'];
    $_SESSION['password'] = $info['password']; 
}
```

Comment: Why separate `isset()` calls? That's not necessary.

Comment: This isset($_SESSION['username'], $_SESSION['password'], $_SESSION['user_id'], $_SESSION['role'])) is wrong, i just correct the syntax.

Comment: @NeedhiAgrawal you can use multiple check with comma separate in isset() follow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14476609/php-isset-with-multiple-parameters