# Check if multiple "post" values are set

Tags: php, ajax

I have this ajax call:

```
 "ajax": {
        url: "fetch.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
          start_date: start_date,
          end_date: end_date
        }
      },
```

Now I need to check in my fetch.php if "start_date" and "end_date" are both set.

I tried it like that but it doesn´t work:

```
if (isset($_POST['start_date'] and $_POST['end_date'])) {
```

This doesn´twork neither:

```
if !empty($_POST['start_date']) && !empty($_POST['end_date'])
    $_POST['start_date'] &&
    $_POST['end_date']
{
```

Where is the mistake?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP isset() with multiple parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14476609/php-isset-with-multiple-parameters)

Comment: Sadly not, I´ve updated my initial post with what I´ve tried.

Answer (score 0):

Your have to access $_POST['data'] and then json encode it.

```
$data = json_encode($_POST['data'],true);
if (isset($data['start_date'] and $data['end_date'])) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You can you use comma to separate your variables

```
if(isset($_POST['start_date'], $_POST['end_date'])) {}
```