# How to use && opertor with checkboxes in php

Tags: php, checkbox, operator-keyword

I am trying to fetch data from MySQL database in PHP based on checkbox selected. i am fine when a single checkbox is selected then it should fetch me some data from the database, but when two or more checkboxes are selected it is not fetching the right data but coming as if it is only one checkbox selected.

example:

checkbox1 to display firstname, checkbox2 to display lastname. when checkbox1 and checkbox2 are selected should display firstname and lastname but it is only displaying firstname.

```
if(isset($_POST["Export"])){

    if(isset($firstname)){

        $sql = "SELECT firstname from biodata";
        $stmt = $pdo->query($sql);
    }
    elseif(isset($lastname)){

        $sql = "SELECT lastname from biodata";
        $stmt = $pdo->query($sql);
    }
   
    if(isset($firstname && $lastname)){

        $sql = "SELECT firstname,lastname from biodata";
        $stmt = $pdo->query($sql);
    }
}
```

Comment: you don't have to use `&&` in the 3rd `isset()`. `isset($firstname , $lastname)`will return true only if all arguments to `isset()` are set and do not contain `null`.

Comment: thanks with your response even with that it is not solved it...

Answer (score 2):

Demo: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/0aix-4tdb

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <span>Select languages</span><br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name='lang[]' value="PHP"> PHP <br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name='lang[]' value="JavaScript"> JavaScript <br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name='lang[]' value="jQuery"> jQuery <br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name='lang[]' value="Angular JS"> Angular JS <br/>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    if(!empty($_POST['lang'])) {

        foreach($_POST['lang'] as $value){
            echo $value.'<br/>';
        }

    }

}
?>
```

Comment: This is not working

Answer (score 0):

you don't have to use `&&` in the 3rd `isset()`.

[isset()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) will return true only if all arguments to `isset()` are set and do not contain `null`

So instead of doing,

```
if(isset($firstname && $lastname)){
    
            $sql = "SELECT firstname,lastname from biodata";
            $stmt = $pdo->query($sql);
}
```

do,

```
if(isset($firstname , $lastname)){
    
            $sql = "SELECT firstname,lastname from biodata";
            $stmt = $pdo->query($sql);
 }
```

For further details, you can visit [PHP isset() with multiple parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14476609/php-isset-with-multiple-parameters)

Comment: If the question is answered by another question on SO, then it should normally be flagged for closure as a duplicate (or leave a comment saying which question which you believe it is a duplicate of and someone else can close it).